# mozCancelFullScreen() not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, html5-video

I've created a button to run `mozCancelFullScreen()` method as to exit from the fullscreen mode. I am not sure why it doesn't run. No error is shown. `mozRequestFullScreen()` works fine for me.

```
$('.screenChange').click(function() { 
    if (video.mozFullscreen) { 
        video.mozCancelFullScreen(); 
    } else if (!video.mozFullscreen) { 
       video.mozRequestFullScreen(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code that calls mozRequestFullScreen()?

Comment: $('.screenChange').click(function() {
if (video.mozFullscreen){
                             video.mozCancelFullScreen();
               
             }else if (!video.mozFullscreen){
                             video.mozRequestFullScreen();

              }
});

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue seems to be in your conditional. "mozFullscreen" is not a property on the video element. Rather, when an element is fullscreen,

```
document.mozFullScreen
```

is true.

There is another problem in that mozCancelFullScreen() is not a method of the video element. It is a method of the document itself. In light of these two corrections, you code should be

```
$('.screenChange').click(function() { 
    if (document.mozFullScreen) { 
        document.mozCancelFullScreen(); 
    } else { 
        video.mozRequestFullScreen(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Peter Maag, I've tried your suggested method but still not working. Or are there methods to use to exit video full screen mode?

Comment: I spun up a demo on my machine and everything works fine. Are you sure that "video" is the actual DOM element (not a jQuery object)? Did you notice that the first two references to "video" in your code have been changed to "document"?

Comment: Thanks Peter Maag I've got it. 

But once i call the mozCancelFullScreen(), I won't be able to call mozRequestFullScreen() again.

Comment: Hi there, i have also been having the same issue as this and your code works but only explicitly on the click of a DOM element. I am trying to fire the mozCancelFullScreen method when the video has ended and it just won't work at all. Why would this work on a click but not a video ended event? Thanks